# Why this plant attracts a lot of flies?

Tags: identification, insects

I have planted a few of these plants in front of my fence as hedge.

[image]

However for some reason they attract a lot of flies to fly around and stop on the flowers.

Why is it and how can I stop the flies?

Location: Sydney, Australia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks to be Euonymus japonicus in full flower - unfortunately, flies are very attracted to the flowers on these. Whilst we don't usually consider flies as pollinating  insects, preferring to mention bees and hoverflies instead, they do actually pollinate plants, and this plant is one they really like. I'm afraid the only way to dispense with the flies is to prune the shrub back, removing all the flowers, which is a pity because then you won't get the rather attractive berries in autumn. Alternatively, just wait; once the flowers fade, the flies will leave the shrub alone. There's a home made recipe here https://www.ehow.com/how_8583077_rid-flies-euonymus.html if you really want to  try spraying; I wouldn't recommend using a proper  insecticide because it will kill other insects like bees as well.

The only thing to check is whether there's a Euonymus Scale infestation - have a close look, particularly at the lower leaves, under and on top of the leaves to make sure that isn't present - that will attract flies too, but it is more likely the presence of flowers causing the issue. https://www.rhs.org.uk/advice/profile?pid=798

Answer (score 2):

Had the same bush. The way to stop it is cut it down replant something totally different.  There a nice shrub in the spring and fall. But in the heat of summer the flies are something out of a horror movie.we actually thought there might have been something dead under there. But each year it got worse and new breeds of flies started showing up. I've never seen so many different flies. If you hit the bush with a mop handle. It looks like thousands of flies come out of it. So like I said. Get rid of it.